# Passing local url through class

Tags: python

I want to pass a url through an another class an use it to show a picture

I tried to pass my variable through a Stringvar(because it is the only way I know) but I get an error PY_VAR3

```py
class pageFunction(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        def meteo(self):
        image_url = url <---- This variable I want to pass it to page1
class page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller

        img = Image.open(--->I want to put my variable here<---)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

I want to pass my variable from pageFunction to page1

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: How do the two classes interact? you're already passing in parameters to the init, you just need to do the same thing again

Comment: First of all, I just started to learn coding. I watch Sentdex on Youtube. I tried to pass image_url in 3 different ways. 1) self.image_url 2) controller.image_url 3) image_url  but none work

Comment: Where and how do you create an instance of you class `page1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here an exmple how to use kwargs

```
args = ("Geeks", "for", "Geeks") 
myFun(*args) 

kwargs = {"arg1" : "Geeks", "arg2" : "for", "arg3" : "Geeks"} 
myFun(**kwargs)
```

so just  like this in your code

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        def meteo(self):
            for arg in args:  ############
                image_url = arg  ##########
   class page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,arg):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller

        img = Image.open(arg)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```